# Changing Liferay war file context root on JBoss EAP

Tags: jboss, liferay, war

I am trying to deploy Liferay 6.2 CE GA4 WAR file on my JBoss EAP 6.4 server with a specified context root. We already have an application with the context defined as "/" and this is what Liferay defaults to. I have tried following with no luck:

- Specifying /liferay as the context root in `jboss-web.xml`
- Creating `portal-ext.properties` in WEB-INF/classes and including `portal.ctx=/liferay`
- Adding -

  `<context-param>
      <param-name>root_path</param-name>
      <param-value>/liferay</param-value>
  </context-param>`

  to `web.xml`

Ultimately I want `http://localhost:8080/liferay` to bring me to the Liferay application, not `http://localhost:8080`. Does anyone have any other suggestions or things that worked for them? I can post full file contents if it would shed more light on my problem.

UPDATE: Here is my JBoss `server.log` where it is trying to register the context:

`16:15:52,652 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-9) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "liferay.war" (runtime-name: "liferay.war")
16:16:04,500 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 324) JBAS018210: Register web context: /liferay
16:16:04,547 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015859: Deployed "liferay.war" (runtime-name : "liferay.war")
16:16:04,547 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014776:    Newly corrected services:
      service jboss.deployment.unit."liferay-fresh.war".component."com.liferay.alloy.taglib.alloy.AioTag".START (no longer required)
      service jboss.deployment.unit."liferay-fresh.war".component."com.liferay.alloy.taglib.alloy.AutoCompleteTag".START (no longer required)
      service jboss.deployment.unit."liferay-fresh.war".component."com.liferay.alloy.taglib.alloy.ButtonItemTag".START (no longer required)`

Comment: Usually the server log should mention under which context path Liferay is deployed (something like `Register web context: /liferay`). Did you try `http://localhost:8080/liferay/` as well?

Comment: It looks like it is trying to deploy to the specified context but the actual page is not accessible there. It returns a 404 error

Comment: What about my second question? Did you try `http://localhost:8080/liferay/` (with the slash at the end)?

Comment: >It returns a 404 error

Comment: According to https://www.liferay.com/de/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/user-guide/-/ai/making-liferay-coexist-with-other-java-ee-applicatio-3 you don't need the `portal.ctx` and `root_path` any more. Try to debug and set a breakpoint in `InvokerFilter.doFilter()`.